# C# - WPF - Unified time of counter execution

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface, animation, counter

I have a piece of code that gather directory data and populate it to fields (for ex size).
Plan is to update the UI fields like counters, hence I've done something like this:

```
        int fileCount //pupulated from another class
        Thread t = new Thread(() =>
        {
            for (int i = 1; i < fileCount; ++i)
            {
                (sender as Button).Dispatcher.Invoke(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Normal,
                    new Action(delegate ()
                    {
                        FileCountBox.Text = i.ToString();
                    }));
                Thread.Sleep(10);
            }
        });
        t.IsBackground = true;
        t.Start();
```

Issue is that some folders may have 10 items and some may have 100k items.
Is there a way to set a execution time limit so TextBlock will be updated faster for those large directories?

One thing that I have in mind would be to make Thread.Sleep() dependent on value of fileCount.

```
switch (fileCount)
case fileCount < 100: y=10
case fileCount < 1000: y=1
(...)
Thread.Sleep(y);
```

Is there a better approach?

Comment: There is [DispatcherTimer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer). You can use it to synchronize UI periodically with data produced by some thread.

Comment: Why do you want to sleep at all?

Comment: frankly I do not know any better way - that's why I've asked if there is a better approach :) I've made it go to sleep in order to see the incrementation in UI and It works as intended. I just want the execution time to be unified for those small and large numbers ex. 100 items would be counted from 1 to 100 in 1 sec and same for 1 to 100k items.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could vary both the delay and the amount you increase per iteration.

You should almost always avoid thread.sleep now await Task.Delay() is available.

This code will give a maximum of 101 steps:

```
    private async void animateDisplay(int count)
    {
        int increment = count / 100;
        if(increment < 0)
        {
            increment = 1;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i+=increment)
        {
            FileCountBox.Text = i.ToString();
            await Task.Delay(10);
        }
        FileCountBox.Text = count.ToString();
    }
```

You just pass in filecount.
I'd guess you won't have 100k in a folder very often but most of the numbers would be a blur anyhow if you reduced the time in the delay down and used a smaller increment.

Comment: Works like a charm (ﾉ◕ヮ◕)ﾉ*:･ﾟ✧